# Give a path of Google Drive to which Google Earth Engine should export the file to

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, file-path

My question is similar to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/324121/concatenating-export-path-in-google-earth-engine) one, with the only difference that:

1. the question in the link above is 3 years old
2. I have one main Folder, inside that folder, I have 11 subfolders, and inside each of the 11 subfolders I have 5 subfolders. The 11 subfolders have different names but the 5 subfolders inside them they have the same name. Below you can see the structure (apologies for the bad hand writing)

[image: main and sub]

The picture above shows the main folder, called Landsat-5, and the 11 subfolders.

[image: sub-subfolders]

The picture above shows the subfolders, inside one of the subfolders.

My goal is to store different exports from `Google Earth Engine` (GEE) in separate subfolders on my `Google Drive`. I'm using `Export.image.toDrive`:

Export.image.toDrive({
image: export_img,
folder: export_path,
fileNamePrefix: filename,
});
Like in the question I provided in the attached link, I tried the same things and had the same results, it just creates a folder with a corresponding name in my Drive root folder.

Is there to a way to specify a path (e.g., Landsat-5/london/2015) to the `Export.Image.toDrive` command?

Comment: Not an answer. I've had similar experiences. I don't bother trying to use subdirectories any more. I just use some local scripting to move the files from the main folder in Google Drive that I use for the downloads to the subdirectories I want to use.

Comment: It seems that there is no way to set subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately. You have to give your folders unique names (perhaps 'L5_Lon_15') or move the exported result in some other systematic way.